# Show that this formula has no Herbrand model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I have the given formula $$A = P(a) \wedge \forall x(P(x)\rightarrow (\exists y Q(x,y)))\wedge (\exists x\neg Q(x,a))$$, and have to show that it has no Herbrand model.

As far as I know, i have to convert it in Skolem Normal Form, then get the Herbrand Expansion and use Resolution to show that the formula is unsatisfiable.

My Skolem Normal Form looks like this: $$\forall x(P(a)\wedge (\neg P(x)\vee Q(x,f(x)))\wedge \neg Q(c,a))$$

But I have no clue how to show that this is unsatisfiable.

Are my steps so far even correct, and what can I do next?

Comment: Disclaimer: I know basically nothing about Herbrand models. But isn't there a theorem that a sentence in Skolem normal form is satisfiable if and only if it has a Herbrand model? If this is true, your sentence must have a Herbrand model, since it is satisfiable.

Comment: Maybe the point is that the original sentence $A$ has no Herbrand model (i.e. no model with just a single element $a$, since there are no other terms formable from the symbols in $A$)? So this serves as an example showing that Skolem normal form is necessary for the theorem I mentioned in my last comment to be true, since $A$ is satisfiable but has no Herbrand model? But this is just speculation. And there are much simpler examples, like $P(a)\land \exists x\, \lnot P(x)$.

Comment: Ah, yes. The Logic course by Prof. Lin. Guess what I'm studying for right now.